# MFA not being return after add accounts for Dag Site SecurityQA

Tags: c#, yodlee

I'm currently at a stage where i can log a user into their bank account using the DAG testing banks.

For a bank that does not require any MFA is working fine (bank Dag Site)

So i figured i'd move on and start implementing functionality for Q/A MFA using the bank (Dag Site SecurityQA)

Upon doing the login for the bank(SecurityQA) i am able to login straight away. I was not returned any form of Question / Answer model.

so i thought id try another bank (DagSiteMFAAndNoMFA) and again nothing returned in the model of any questions or security questions.

I've checked the response from when the Accounts are added for the MFA.
I've checked the webhook data that is returned if the model is there for MFA.

No form of MFA questions.

I've been referring to this document to get the idea of the Yodlee REFRESH concept.

https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/Webhooks/Refresh_Event

Are you able to tell me where i can get this Question/Answer / Token / Capture data from when the account is added? I just seem to be logging straight in for all the accounts?

I can also check that the accounts are added via the website api
https://developer.api.yodlee.com:443/ysl/restserver/v1/accounts

and the accounts are added but shouldn't be because i have not answered any form of MFA

Based on other peoples questions regarding MFA i see that people are using getMFAResponseForSite but im not sure if these are old Yodlee api calls and they have improved since then.

thanks

Comment: Hey, Have you got any solution for it?

Comment: yes mate, go here https://dag2.yodlee.com/dag/dhaction.do and use the username and password bank the testing bank site you want to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, goto https://dag2.yodlee.com/dag/dhaction.do and then login, use the banking username and password for the particualr MFA you want to use. e.g. the username for Dag Site Captcha is Ko******.site18769.1 and password is site18769.1.

This then will return the login form.

If the then download the the bank info you can see the test answers for you to get the SUCCESS.

let me know if you need any more help. thanks